# HTML5: manipulating browser windows

Tags: html

Does HTML5 give the ability to directly manipulate browser windows (like switching a window to the foreground, closing it, getting its name and contents, etc) even if my window doesn't "own" them?

I realize this is a security risk, but I would like to at least do this on my local system where I can provide privileged permission to a script if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to make a Firefox add on or Chromium add on.  It's the only way you are truly going to be able to gain access to the things you are wanting access to.

Comment: In Firefox, XUL would be something to look into.

Comment: I'm specifically interested in cross-browser HTML5.

Comment: It's not possible.  The only way you can get access to these things is if you create a plugin or directly modify the source code of a browser such as XUL for Firefox like Rob mentioned.  Neither options are cross-browser and there are simply no other options for you.  I am afraid you need to either decide to target one browser or scale down your ambitions.